# Unable to send email with libcurl (cross compiled for arm) application

Tags: linux, arm, libcurl

I am using [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) for [am-1808](http://www.ti.com/product/am1808) running linux[i need to send emails with my c-program], i have compiled the libcurl successfully for arm and the [sample application](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-multi.html) gets compiled successfully, but when i run this application on arm-board, i got the following output.

```
* About to connect() to smtp.gmail.com port 587 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.127.108... * 0x12008 is at send pipe head!
* Connected to smtp.gmail.com (74.125.127.108) port 587 (#0)
< 220 mx.google.com ESMTP pf8sm6421301pbc.44
> EHLO am180x-evm
< 250-mx.google.com at your service, [115.186.161.64]
< 250-SIZE 35882577
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250-STARTTLS
< 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
> STARTTLS
< 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
> QUIT
```

And then it remains stuck there, the output of the same program on my pc is,

```
* About to connect() to smtp.gmail.com port 587 (#0)
*   Trying 74.125.127.108...
* Connected to smtp.gmail.com (74.125.127.108) port 587 (#0)
* Connected to smtp.gmail.com (74.125.127.108) port 587 (#0)
< 220 mx.google.com ESMTP ns5sm15912240pbb.26
> EHLO ubuntu
< 250-mx.google.com at your service, [115.186.161.64]
< 250-SIZE 35882577
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250-STARTTLS
< 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
> STARTTLS
< 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=smtp.gmail.com
*    start date: 2011-11-18 01:57:17 GMT
*    expire date: 2012-11-18 02:07:17 GMT
*    issuer: C=US; O=Google Inc; CN=Google Internet Authority
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> EHLO ubuntu
< 250-mx.google.com at your service, [115.186.161.64]
< 250-SIZE 35882577
< 250-8BITMIME
< 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH
< 250 ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
> AUTH LOGIN dXNhbWF5YXNlZW45MEBnbWFpbC5jb20=
< 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
> dXNhenJwMjY=
< 235 2.7.0 Accepted
> MAIL FROM:<my_email@gmail.com>
< 250 2.1.0 OK ns5sm15912240pbb.26
> RCPT TO:<my_email@yahoo.com>
< 250 2.1.5 OK ns5sm15912240pbb.26
> DATA
< 354  Go ahead ns5sm15912240pbb.26
< 250 2.0.0 OK 1342605604 ns5sm15912240pbb.26
* Connection #0 to host smtp.gmail.com left intact
> QUIT
< 221 2.0.0 closing connection ns5sm15912240pbb.26
* Closing connection #0
```

There is some issue with the certificates, i have tried setting ca-bundle while configuring lib-curl, but it didn't helped. Here's my command for configuring libcurl.

```
./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --build=i686-linux CFLAGS='-Os' --with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt --with-ssl=/usr/bin/openssl --enable-smtp
```

Any idea how i can fix this ?

regards

usama

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lib-curl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) require [openssl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) for enabling https, ssl etc , now i had openssl installed on my system but that was compiled for x64 processor, so i cross-compiled open-ssl for arm and after that i cross-compiled lib-curl again for arm and now that [sample applicatio](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/smtp-multi.html)n is working fine and sending email.

The configure parameter for open-ssl are:

```
./config os/compiler:arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc
```

The configure parameter for lib-curl are:

```
./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --build=i686-linux CFLAGS='-Os' --enable-smtp --with-ssl
```

If you still are getting certificate error than add this to the configure parameters.

```
--with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

**P.S: Before running application on arm, don't forget to copy the include and lib files from your pc to arm.**